# Amazon Sagemaker: write your own inference

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I was evaluating what is needed to write your own Estimator in Sagemaker. I was following this example [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container) and it's well explained and quite simple.

My question is regarding the inference [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees/predictor.py). I see an example in which we can feed the [invocations endpoint](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/e648e9a6f596263c7683635d1a55f1729b08277d/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees/predictor.py#L60) a CSV. What if I want to just post a string or even individual parameters? What's the best practise for that? I see there is a condition like:

```
if flask.request.content_type == "text/csv":
```

Should we add more like those to support different formats or should we create a new endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add support for more content types.

Since you would like to pass a string or a parameter, I suggest you add support for "application/json" MIME media type ([What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)). Then your users will call the API with a Json that you can parse and extract parameters from in the backend.

For example, if you have two parameters `age` and `gender` you want to pass to your model. You can put them in the following Json datastructure:

```json
{
 "age": ...,
 "gender": ...
}
```

Then add support for loading the Json and extracting the parameters in the backend as follows:

```py
if flask.request.content_type == "application/json":
    data = flask.request.data.decode("utf-8")
    data = json.loads(data)
    parameter1 = data['age']
    parameter2 = data['gender']
    ...
```